# How to test a hot fix on Play Store Internal Test track when there is a higher version available?

Tags: android, google-play

I currently work with all tracks on the Play Store and the released versions look like this:

- Internal Test - version 2.1
- Alpha - version 2.0
- Beta - version 2.0
- Production - version 1.3

The problem I am facing is, assuming the example above, if I find a critical bug on version 1.3 and would like to release a version 1.4 with just that fix, would that be possible? Since test tracks are already on 2.X, is it possible to release 1.4 there to test the fix?

I know from [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) that users will only receive the highest version they have available. So, unless I can downgrade the Internal test track (and ask testers to uninstall 2.X), I don't see how this would be possible. However it would be a big problem for hot fixes. I know iOS TestFlight supports this.

Comment: Just a note to readers, "Internal app sharing" section (not to be confused with "Internal test track") allow to downgrade easily (without `adb` and `bundletool`) because it can hold multiple invitation links, Tester require enable developer settings by pressing "Play Store version" 7 times and toggle on "Internal app sharing"  settings on play store app in their phone before able to use the link.